# How to make website preview using javascript

Tags: javascript

what is my best shot to ensure web page preview from web application?
In application, user should be able to select specific URL and get web preview from
that URL. I tried with iframe but some services are refusing GET request from iframe.
Any other options?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you are asking, but maybe the jQuery load method will help you - https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Use proxy script `<iframe src="proxy/?url=tasdfasd.asd">` - this is the most reliable way.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have pre-stored images. Javascript cannot take screenshots and resize the images (for now). Try this: http://snapcasa.com/ . It takes images dynamically for you. All you have to do is to hot link the images :)

The best features when using http://snapcasa.com/:

- Images are guaranteed to be most up-to-date
- You don't have to store them on your server!
- Free plan has lots of credits for you to burn!

You can have a free API if you want ;)

Comment: Good tip but it's not an option since it takes too much time to render.

Answer (score 1):

As dfsq suggested, proxy is the easiest way to solve the problem. Since this is a djnago application, I setup http proxy method and now it's working like a charm.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

In Mozilla you can take a snapshot of any element on the page through the [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/element). Currently only FF supports it.

```
background: -moz-element(#mysite);
```

Here `#mysite` is the element whose content is used as background.
[**http://jsfiddle.net/qu2kz/3/**](http://jsfiddle.net/qu2kz/3/) *(tested on FF 27)*

[image: Sample]